# Semantic UI doesn't work with the sass gem for my ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I've followed every instruction online for solving this problem.

I added

```
gem 'semantic-ui-sass'
```

to my Gemfile.

Added

```
//= require jquery
//= require semantic-ui
```

to my application.js file. Some said adding the require jquery would work. Also put

```
@import "semantic-ui";
```

in a custom scss file named application.css.scss. But when I try putting a code snippet on a view file it never loads properly.

Any  idea why that may be?

Comment: Did you run `bundle`?

Comment: Yes, I also just tried using another library like MaterilizeCSS and it also didn't work at all after doing similar steps. Maybe it's a problem with my local machine. Although Bootstrap did work for me.

Comment: I have the same situation righ now, I'm trying to figure it out,  maybe the problem is in application.js when require bootstrap and semantic-ui ( using both gems at same time)

Comment: I haven't found a better solution, but for a while you can try specifying the id of your element in application.js Something like $('#name_id').dropdown();